# How to avoid conditional statements inside a vertex shader?

Tags: vertex-shader

How can I avoid the conditional statement of the following code snippet of the vertex shader? What is an improved way of writing the below?

```
uniform float some_value;
in vec4 a_position;
in vec2 a_texcoord;                                                  
out vec2 v_texcoord;

void main (){
    if (position.x > some_value){
      a_texcoord = a_texcoord.st * vec2(1.0, -1.0);
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(a_position.x, -a_position.y, a_position.z, 1.0);
    }
    else{
       a_texcoord = a_texcoord;
       gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your two branches only differ by a sign flip, so you can use [the step function](https://docs.gl/sl4/step) to compute the sign you want to use, then multiply by this sign unconditionally.

```
// -1.0 if x > some_value, +1.0 otherwise
float flip = -1.0f + 2.0f * step(position.x, some_value);

a_texcoord *= vec2(1.0f, flip);

gl_Position = projectionMatrix 
            * modelViewMatrix 
            * vec4( a_position.x, 
                    flip * a_position.y,
                    a_position.z, 
                    1.0
            );
```

Though be sure to profile this versus the original code. This is verging on a micro-optimization, and depending on the graphics card and how clever the shader compiler is, might not get you much performance benefit.

It does come at a cost of legibility though: I'll confess, I can *never* remember which way the arguments go in a `step`, and whether equality gives a 0 or a 1 — even now I'm *still* anxious I got it wrong above. That's a problem the clear and simple branch doesn't have.